# How is Kyrie Irving body stay balanced in inclined position?

Tags: statics

How can we explain this in a scientific way? As far as I understand, your body will stay balanced if the projection of your center of gravity to the ground is still between the area covered by your legs (figure given to illustrate).

However, Kyrie Irving is obviously inclined here, and from what I know you can't hold a structure inclined by just the internal forces (correct me if I'm wrong), and that internal forces in this case is human muscle. Even if we bent down, we slightly move our buttocks behind, thus making our CoG stays within the area.

How is this possible? Free body diagram explaining this will be nice.

[image]

[image]

Video of him doing it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyDhSa4qJbQ

Comment: "*How is this possible?*" It's not. Notice the video has many occurrences of  people blocking the view and his left hand goes out of frame on the sideways lean. Heavy weights low down on his body would be my best guess and possibly a helper in the sideways lean. As you suspect, once his centre of gravity (CoG) goes past the support point he should fall over.

Comment: Could also be a photo just before he steps forward to catch his fall.

Comment: [It' magic!](https://celticswire.usatoday.com/2018/11/27/kyrie-irving-all-but-admits-viral-video-of-his-balancing-act-is-fake/)

Comment: Yeah, the trick, or the magic, is on the shoes.

Comment: don't assume that volume is equivalent to mass or that the iceberg is all above the water.

Comment: this belongs on a magician's forum, not engineering.

Comment: This trick can also be done with a clear and effectively invisible fishing line supporting him, either from above or from behind

Comment: what about the limits of the center of gravity?

Comment: Depleted-uranium shoes.

Answer (score 0):

Kyrie showed micheal jackson that move

Comment: Although this is a cute joke, it fundamentally doesn't answer the question and should get closed. As you gain reputation you'll gain the ability to post comments.